# About opening Adobe InDesign indd file in Ubuntu

Tags: adobe

I have read this post and tried to install **[scribus](https://www.scribus.net/)** for opening the **Indd** file, but as you can see it could not open the adobe InDesign indd file :
[image]

So, if possible, I have asked here to find out how to find out open it on Ubuntu 18.04? Or any online site to convert it to acceptable **Scribus** input format (like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497493/how-to-convert-indesign-indd-file-to-idml-file-and-back-online-or-without) or [this](https://markzware.com/products/markztools2/))?

Thanks.